# Visual Studio - Collapse Branch Folders by default in Team Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I was wondering if there was a way to collapse these git categories in Team Explorer by default. My list of branches grow daily and even after deleting unused branches, it's still getting larger. Being able to collapse some or all of these folders by default would be very helpful. Preferably without extensions as this is my work computer and I'd like to minimize my installed extensions list.

Removed branch names for privacy

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this time, however, it is not supported to collapse branch folders by default.

But there is a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/599559/team-explorer-changes-add-expand-all-and-collapse.html) on Microsoft's developer Community that wants to add the "Collapse All" button.

This feature request is currently under consideration. You can vote for it or give a comment, and Microsoft will consider your request.

Comment: Disheartening to hear that it’s been a feature request for a year and a half but I guess no way around it.